# How to remove "FOR UPDATE OF" syntax either in DASHDB or OpenOfficeCalc?

Tags: analytics, openoffice-calc, dashdb

I am connecting to DashDB thru an ODBC connection in OpenOfficeCalc. I can correctly display tables.

However, I am not able to display any data, because OpenOffice appends FOR UPDATE clause to SELECT statement, making DashDB send back SQL1667, clause not supported for ORGANIZED BY COLUMN tables.

I don't see any option to remove this in OpenOffice, is there a way to tell DashDB to ignore such clauses ?

Comment: Not sure about DashDB, but from the OpenOffice side, how precisely are you connecting?  Is it really Calc and not Base?  Also, it sounds like you marked "Open the database for editing" -- was that intentional?  Whatever the case, you could write a macro to do the query, allowing full control over the SQL.

Comment: Hi Jim, From Calc I opened new ODBC datasource, and there is no way I cannot open it for read only. The only choice is open for editing as you point out. If I don't click this box, I have no access to DB.

Comment: It sounds like you connected by going to File -> New -> Database, which creates a new Base file.  "I have no access to DB" -- so Base does not show any tables at all if the box is unchecked, whereas if the box is checked, Base shows tables but does not display their data?  Strange behavior, but try a macro using [the DataSource service](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/Database/The_DataSource_Service).